# Get maximum value by group with additional constraints

Tags: r, tibble

I have a data.frame with 4 variables: **day** (Date, format: "YYYY-MM-DD"), **hour** (POSIXct, format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"), **department** (chr) and **amount** (numeric).

```
df <- structure(list(
day = structure(c(18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116), class = "Date"), 
hour = structure(c(1565275500, 1565276400, 1565277300, 1565278200, 1565279100, 1565280000, 1565280900, 1565281800, 1565282700, 1565275500, 1565276400, 1565277300, 1565278200, 1565279100, 1565280000, 1565280900, 1565281800, 1565282700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
department = c("DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2"), 
amount = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0), max_cond = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each row of the data.frame I want to get the maximum value of **amount**, grouped by **day** and **department**, BUT ONLY for the hours of the day that are greater or equal to the **hour** of the respective row.

In other words, for each observation [*day_i, hour_i, department_i*] I want to get: max(**amount** | (**day** == *day_i*) *&* (**department** == *department_i*) *&* (**hour** >= *hour_i*)).

For the example above, we should have:

```
          day                hour department amount max_cond
1  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00       DPT1      2        3
2  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:00:00       DPT1      3        3
3  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:15:00       DPT1      3        3
4  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:30:00       DPT1      2        2
5  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:45:00       DPT1      0        2
6  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:00:00       DPT1      0        2
7  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:15:00       DPT1      1        2
8  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:30:00       DPT1      2        2
9  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:45:00       DPT1      1        1
10 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00       DPT2      3        3
11 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:00:00       DPT2      3        3
12 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:15:00       DPT2      3        3
13 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:30:00       DPT2      2        3
14 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:45:00       DPT2      2        3
15 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:00:00       DPT2      3        3
16 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:15:00       DPT2      0        0
17 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:30:00       DPT2      0        0
18 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 13:45:00       DPT2      0        0
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, could you show what has failed and how? How is `hour >= hour_i)` defined, what is the reference hour?

Comment: The reference `hour_i` is the value of the variable **hour** for the "i-th" row.I am used to using `dplyr::` for calculating summary statistics within groups, but the additional constraint `hour >= hour_i` makes it trickier.

Comment: If we're at row 1(i==1), then hour_i == `11:45:00`, so do we check that `11:45>11:45`? It seems I'm either misunderstanding, or you really should do a general filter?

Comment: That is correct. I want to calculate the maximum value of "amount" only for the subset of observations for which `hour >= hour_i` (and that are within the same group of **day** and **department** of observation "i"). Consider that we are at row 4 (i == 4). Then I want "max_cond" to be max_cond_4 = max(2,0,0,1,2,1) = 2.

Comment: Using a for loop plus a general filter would probably do it, but I was looking for a more elegant (and hopefully faster) approach. Could data.table do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar, but using `data.table` you could do:

```
library(data.table)

df <- structure(list(
  day = structure(c(18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116, 18116), class = "Date"), 
  hour = structure(c(1565275500, 1565276400, 1565277300, 1565278200, 1565279100, 1565280000, 1565280900, 1565281800, 1565282700, 1565275500, 1565276400, 1565277300, 1565278200, 1565279100, 1565280000, 1565280900, 1565281800, 1565282700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
  department = c("DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT1", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2", "DPT2"), 
  amount = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0), max_cond = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

dt = data.table(df)
setorder(dt, -hour)
dt[,max_cond_new:=cummax(amount),by=.(day,department)]
setorder(dt, department, hour)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, no problem @pabc! Cannot recommend `data.table` enough, especially for large data sets. If this solved your issue, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `base` R approach: you could use `cummax()` (**cum**ulative **max**imum) to solve this problem. **Note that I am assuming your data frame has sorted `hour`s,** which is the case in your example.

The idea is: to first `split()` the data frame into components with distinct `date`s and `department`s. Then, within each component:

- reverse the relevant vector, `$day`
- construct the `$max_cond` variable (in reverse) with `cummax()`
- flip the `$max_cond` variable back to the correct order

Then, glue all the components back together with `do.call()` and `rbind()`.

For your example:

```
df2 <- split(df, list(df$department, df$day))
df2 <- lapply(df2, function(x) {
  x$max_cond <- x[order(x$hour, decreasing = T), ]$amount %>%
    cummax %>%
    sort(decreasing = T)
  x
})

df2 <- do.call(rbind, df2)
row.names(df2) <- NULL

df2
##           day                hour department amount max_cond
## 1  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:45:00       DPT1      2        3
## 2  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:00:00       DPT1      3        3
## 3  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:15:00       DPT1      3        3
## 4  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:30:00       DPT1      2        2
## 5  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00       DPT1      0        2
## 6  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:00:00       DPT1      0        2
## 7  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:15:00       DPT1      1        2
## 8  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:30:00       DPT1      2        2
## 9  2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:45:00       DPT1      1        1
## 10 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 10:45:00       DPT2      3        3
## 11 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:00:00       DPT2      3        3
## 12 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:15:00       DPT2      3        3
## 13 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:30:00       DPT2      2        3
## 14 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 11:45:00       DPT2      2        3
## 15 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:00:00       DPT2      3        3
## 16 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:15:00       DPT2      0        0
## 17 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:30:00       DPT2      0        0
## 18 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 12:45:00       DPT2      0        0
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my data.frame is not split off into single (day / department) pieces =/. Sorry if my example was not clear. I have a really big data.frame, so solving the "grouping part" of the problem is also crucial...

Comment: Understood. Could you update your MWE to include that behavior, then? (Unfortunately I have to leave my computer for a few hours, so I won't be able to amend the post for a while. Someone else is likely to provide a better answer, though.)

Comment: Ok. Updated the MWE.

Comment: Updated the answer, though I think Patrick Altmeyer's `data.table` solution is probably better.